# Jquery refreshing page on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, shopify

I am using shopify custom build web site,

today I figured out my website is refreshing automatically on safari.

I removed jquery in order to test and website stopped refreshing.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Ps: After 2 refreshes website crashes at safari (it refreshed only if I do not touch to website)

[my website](https://www.morphosleep.com/)

Comment: I think it is better to ask the technical support of this company instead of asking here

Comment: @erorprograms if you check the website you fill see the jquery is the latest version of original cdn. I gave every detail on my question. Btw I am the technical support of the company.